# (SOLVED) Get #NAME? from Make (Integromat) Google Sheet module when I use a function created in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, make.com, integromat-apps

I have a Google Sheets document based on responses from a Google Forms form.
In this document I validate the data received with different functions.
For example, I create a username by concatenating the contents of cell one and cell two, etc.
In some functions I use other functions created in Google Apps Scripts, such as to validate that the username does not have special characters.

At Google Sheets documents all works fine and the results are correct, but when I try to access from Make (Integromat) I get #NAME? in an intermittent way.

I've diferents functions in the same row and three of them uses a functions created in Google Apps Scripts.
When get #NAME? in firts cell I get the same error on the three cells.
Always from Make results not in Sheets document.

Google Apps Script Function:

```
const latinRegEx = /[\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\xff\u0100-\u017f]/g;
const comboRegEx = `[\\u0300-\\u036f\\ufe20-\\ufe2f\\u20d0-\\u20ff]`;

/** Used to map Latin Unicode letters to basic Latin letters. */
const latinUnicodeLetters = {
  // Latin-1 Supplement block.
  '\xc0': 'A',
  '\xc1': 'A',
  '\xc2': 'A',
  '\xc3': 'A',
  '\xc4': 'A',
  '\xc5': 'A',
  '\xe0': 'a',
  '\xe1': 'a',
  '\xe2': 'a',
  '\xe3': 'a',
  '\xe4': 'a',
  '\xe5': 'a',
  '\xc7': 'C',
  '\xe7': 'c',
  '\xd0': 'D',
  '\xf0': 'd',
  '\xc8': 'E',
  '\xc9': 'E',
  '\xca': 'E',
  '\xcb': 'E',
  '\xe8': 'e',
  '\xe9': 'e',
  '\xea': 'e',
  '\xeb': 'e',
  '\xcc': 'I',
  '\xcd': 'I',
  '\xce': 'I',
  '\xcf': 'I',
  '\xec': 'i',
  '\xed': 'i',
  '\xee': 'i',
  '\xef': 'i',
  '\xd1': 'N',
  '\xf1': 'n',
  '\xd2': 'O',
  '\xd3': 'O',
  '\xd4': 'O',
  '\xd5': 'O',
  '\xd6': 'O',
  '\xd8': 'O',
  '\xf2': 'o',
  '\xf3': 'o',
  '\xf4': 'o',
  '\xf5': 'o',
  '\xf6': 'o',
  '\xf8': 'o',
  '\xd9': 'U',
  '\xda': 'U',
  '\xdb': 'U',
  '\xdc': 'U',
  '\xf9': 'u',
  '\xfa': 'u',
  '\xfb': 'u',
  '\xfc': 'u',
  '\xdd': 'Y',
  '\xfd': 'y',
  '\xff': 'y',
  '\xc6': 'Ae',
  '\xe6': 'ae',
  '\xde': 'Th',
  '\xfe': 'th',
  '\xdf': 'ss',
  // Latin Extended-A block.
  '\u0100': 'A',
  '\u0102': 'A',
  '\u0104': 'A',
  '\u0101': 'a',
  '\u0103': 'a',
  '\u0105': 'a',
  '\u0106': 'C',
  '\u0108': 'C',
  '\u010a': 'C',
  '\u010c': 'C',
  '\u0107': 'c',
  '\u0109': 'c',
  '\u010b': 'c',
  '\u010d': 'c',
  '\u010e': 'D',
  '\u0110': 'D',
  '\u010f': 'd',
  '\u0111': 'd',
  '\u0112': 'E',
  '\u0114': 'E',
  '\u0116': 'E',
  '\u0118': 'E',
  '\u011a': 'E',
  '\u0113': 'e',
  '\u0115': 'e',
  '\u0117': 'e',
  '\u0119': 'e',
  '\u011b': 'e',
  '\u011c': 'G',
  '\u011e': 'G',
  '\u0120': 'G',
  '\u0122': 'G',
  '\u011d': 'g',
  '\u011f': 'g',
  '\u0121': 'g',
  '\u0123': 'g',
  '\u0124': 'H',
  '\u0126': 'H',
  '\u0125': 'h',
  '\u0127': 'h',
  '\u0128': 'I',
  '\u012a': 'I',
  '\u012c': 'I',
  '\u012e': 'I',
  '\u0130': 'I',
  '\u0129': 'i',
  '\u012b': 'i',
  '\u012d': 'i',
  '\u012f': 'i',
  '\u0131': 'i',
  '\u0134': 'J',
  '\u0135': 'j',
  '\u0136': 'K',
  '\u0137': 'k',
  '\u0138': 'k',
  '\u0139': 'L',
  '\u013b': 'L',
  '\u013d': 'L',
  '\u013f': 'L',
  '\u0141': 'L',
  '\u013a': 'l',
  '\u013c': 'l',
  '\u013e': 'l',
  '\u0140': 'l',
  '\u0142': 'l',
  '\u0143': 'N',
  '\u0145': 'N',
  '\u0147': 'N',
  '\u014a': 'N',
  '\u0144': 'n',
  '\u0146': 'n',
  '\u0148': 'n',
  '\u014b': 'n',
  '\u014c': 'O',
  '\u014e': 'O',
  '\u0150': 'O',
  '\u014d': 'o',
  '\u014f': 'o',
  '\u0151': 'o',
  '\u0154': 'R',
  '\u0156': 'R',
  '\u0158': 'R',
  '\u0155': 'r',
  '\u0157': 'r',
  '\u0159': 'r',
  '\u015a': 'S',
  '\u015c': 'S',
  '\u015e': 'S',
  '\u0160': 'S',
  '\u015b': 's',
  '\u015d': 's',
  '\u015f': 's',
  '\u0161': 's',
  '\u0162': 'T',
  '\u0164': 'T',
  '\u0166': 'T',
  '\u0163': 't',
  '\u0165': 't',
  '\u0167': 't',
  '\u0168': 'U',
  '\u016a': 'U',
  '\u016c': 'U',
  '\u016e': 'U',
  '\u0170': 'U',
  '\u0172': 'U',
  '\u0169': 'u',
  '\u016b': 'u',
  '\u016d': 'u',
  '\u016f': 'u',
  '\u0171': 'u',
  '\u0173': 'u',
  '\u0174': 'W',
  '\u0175': 'w',
  '\u0176': 'Y',
  '\u0177': 'y',
  '\u0178': 'Y',
  '\u0179': 'Z',
  '\u017b': 'Z',
  '\u017d': 'Z',
  '\u017a': 'z',
  '\u017c': 'z',
  '\u017e': 'z',
  '\u0132': 'IJ',
  '\u0133': 'ij',
  '\u0152': 'Oe',
  '\u0153': 'oe',
  '\u0149': "'n",
  '\u017f': 's',
};

const basePropertyOf = (object) => (key) => object[key];
const characterMap = basePropertyOf(latinUnicodeLetters);

/**
 * Replace accented characters in Google Sheets with English letters.
 *
 * @param {string} input The input string with accented characters.
 * @return The input without accented characters.
 * @customfunction
 */
function REPLACE_ACCENTED(input) {
  if (input && typeof input === 'string') {
    return input.replace(latinRegEx, characterMap).replace(comboRegEx, '');
  }
  return input;
}
```

Google Sheets function:

```
=SI(C2 <> "" ; SI(LARGO(SUSTITUIR(CONCATENAR(C2;".";D2); " " ; "")) < 20 ; 
SI(O(REGEXMATCH(C2 ; "[^A-Za-z]+") ; REGEXMATCH(D2 ; "[^A-Za-z]+" )) ; REPLACE_ACCENTED(SUSTITUIR(MINUSC(CONCATENAR(C2;".";D2)) ; " " ; "")) ; SUSTITUIR(MINUSC(CONCATENAR(C2;".";D2)) ; " " ; "")) ; SI(O(REGEXMATCH(C2 ; "[^A-Za-z]+") ; REGEXMATCH(D2 ; "[^A-Za-z]+" )) ; EXTRAE(REPLACE_ACCENTED(SUSTITUIR(MINUSC(CONCATENAR(C2;".";D2)); " " ; "")) ; 1 ; 20) ; EXTRAE(SUSTITUIR(MINUSC(CONCATENAR(C2;".";D2)); " " ; "") ; 1 ; 20))) ; "")
```

[[Google Sheet document values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjN4o.png)]
[[Make (Integromat) values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KNPh.png)]

I tried modifying the Google Sheet function by adding `(REGEXMATCH(C2 ; "[^A-Za-z]+)` so that it would only call the Google Apps Script function if special characters were detected in the specified cells.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by copying the data to another sheet of the document `=QUERY` and making Make read from that sheet. Being a copy of the data has no formulas and reads the data directly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).